# Using multiple datasets in same JSON file with d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm attempting to modify the [Line Plus Bar chart](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html) from nvd3 so that when a button is clicked, the chart will switch to data from a different day of the week (Sun-Sat).

Right now I'm having trouble just getting it to display the data from one day of the week; it displays all days of the week for some reason. Here is my code:

```
d3.json("employee_data.json",function(error,data) {
  if(error) return console.warn(error);
  nv.addGraph(function() {
      var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
            .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
            //We can set x data accessor to use index. Reason? So the bars all appear evenly spaced.
            .x(function(d,i) {
              console.log(i)
              return i })
            .y(function(d,i) {
              return d[1] })
            ;

      chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d,i) {
        var dx = data[0].values[i] && data[0].values[i][0] || 0;
        return 'Sun' + dx
      });

      chart.y1Axis
          .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

      chart.y2Axis
          .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(',f')(d) });

      chart.bars.forceY([0]);

      d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(data)
        .transition()
        .duration(0)
        .call(chart);

      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

      return chart;
  });

});
```

The JSON is set up in a manner similar to:

```
[
  {
    "key" : "Sun_Employees",
    "bar" : true,
    "color" : "#ccf",
    "values" : [[0,2],[1,2],[3,2],[4,3],...,[23,1]]
  },
  {
    "key": "Sun_Tasks",
    "color" : "#333",
    "values" : [[0,5],[1,6],[2,5],[3,7],...,[23,2]]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Mon_Employees",
    "bar" : true,
    "color" : "#ccf",
    "values" : [[0,2],[1,2],[3,2],[4,3],...,[23,1]]
  },
  {
    "key": "Mon_Tasks",
    "color" : "#333",
    "values" : [[0,5],[1,6],[2,5],[3,7],...,[23,2]]
  }
}
```

I think the issue has to do with the .x(function(d,i) { return i}) line, but don't know how I would go about limiting it.

Comment: Can you filter the data before binding it to your selection?  This would look something like: ```var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) { return d.key.startsWith("Sun"); }); d3.select('#chart svg').datum(filteredData)...```

Comment: Yes! This worked. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear it!  I converted my comment to an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering the data before binding it to your selection. This would look something like:

```
var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) { return d.key.startsWith("Sun"); });
d3.select('#chart svg')
  .datum(filteredData)
  ...
```